# UICollectionView Crashing

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am creating a  class for collectionView and I am adding the CollectionView to the Viewcontroller for presentation as below

```
 init(){

        let collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
        self.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier_SampleCollectionViewCell)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier_SampleCollectionViewCell, for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIColor.brown
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width - 16, height: 120)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 8
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    }
```

Then I brought this collectionView to MainView controller and initialized and set the delegates as below

```
open lazy var sampleeCollectionView: SampleCollectionView = { [unowned self] in
    let collectionview = SampleCollectionView()
    collectionview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionview.dataSource = self
    collectionview.delegate = self
    return collectionview
}()
```

Currently App is crashing anyone can suggest How can we solve. Here I add the datasource and delegate in the viewController which I am presenting. If i change this to CollectionView Class it is working. Is it possible to keep this in the initializing place

Comment: Care to include actual error message?

Comment: Do add crash log too, or just phrase with terminating app due to etc..

Comment: Please add crash log for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a storyboard and haven't either registered a Xib with your cell or created a prototype in the storyboard with the identifier you're trying to reuse.

Considering you have an init method, it's probably not getting called, so I assume the issue is in the storyboard.

Comment: No I am not using storyboard I am using Constraints

Comment: In that case, it looks like your register method isn't getting fired, place a breakpoint to see if the register method is invoked before cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Add self.delegate = self and self.dataSource = self to your init method